# How to add dynamic column name to subset?

Tags: r

this is part of shiny app, those values came from reactive ui/server, I narrowed down my problem in server.R, and I work with this plain R for simplicity, it should reflect my question correctly I hope, how to make this line with <@><< work ??? I also tried, noquote, `eval` and nothing.

```
t <- data.frame(Titanic)
inputparam = "Class"
inputvalue = "2nd"
c(inputparam, "=",inputvalue)
noquote(inputparam)

head(subset(t, Class ==inputvalue))   ## works OK
head(subset(t, inputparam ==inputvalue))   ## <@>><   doesn't work !!!!!
#temp <- quote(inputparam)
#head(subset(t,  eval(temp) == inputvalue))
```

Comment: without a reproducible example, one can only guess what your problem is. It could be shiny, R or you data...

Comment: You should probably avoid `subset` with its non-standard evaluation for this and use `[` for subsetting. `subset` is documented to be intended for interactive use only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` with parse works

```
eval(parse( text=paste0("subset(t, ", inputparam, "=='", inputvalue, "')") ))
```

The `inputvalue` has to be enclosed as with another quote so that `parse` recognizes it as a `character`.

Alternatively you **should** try something like this, (check comments for reasons)

```
t[ t[colnames(t)==inputparam]==inputvalue, ]
```

Comment: ...and lets just hope `inputvalue` never has any quote marks in it, shall we? No no no no no. Don't even **suggest** that `eval`/`parse` can do something if you have another solution, which you do. You've just given someone a thermonuclear device when all they wanted was a hammer.

Comment: Haha... I just answered in the path OP was trying.. Updated my answer to address your concern.

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen their greyed text which I see now was their nuclear missile program.

Answer (score 1):

Get data frame column by variable *value* using double square brackets, subset using single square brackets. This is R 101:

```
head(t[ t[[inputparam]] ==inputvalue, ])
```

So $-signs get columns by name, which is great, and preferred, if you know the name in advance. Double-square brackets evaluate the contents in the brackets and get by value. You can stick any R expression in there.

Comment: Tx Spacedman and jM!!!   found that this also works .... _head(subset(t, get(inputparam) ==inputvalue))_